# Отправка логов бота дискорд python

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Здраствуйте, сделал систему логов чтобы когда пользователь удалял сообщение то отправлялась в канал для логов, и так же сделал систему авто-удаление сообщения бота, но проблема в том что бот отправляет в логи то что он удалил свое сообщение, можете помочь как сделать что бы бот отправлял только сообщения пользователей а не свое, код снизу, заранее спасибо!

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(logs_test)
    emb = discord.Embed(
        title='Удаление сообщения ',
        color=red,
        timestamp=message.created_at
    )
    emb.add_field(name="Пользователь:", value=f"{message.author.mention}", inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Канал:', value=f'<#{message.channel.id}>', inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Сообщение:', value=f'{message.content}', inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='ID сообщения:', value=f'`{message.id}`', inline=False)
    emb.set_footer(text='Логи Сообщений | Arizona Space')

    await channel.send(embed=emb)
```

```
@bot.command() # clear
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    emb = discord.Embed(
        title='Успешно! ✅',
        timestamp=ctx.created_at,
        description=f'Вы успешно удалили {amount} сообщений!',
        color=green
    )
    
    emb.set_footer(text=f'Написал {ctx.author.name} | Arizona Space')

    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(time_delete)
    await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать проверку сообщения

```py
if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
  pass
else:
  emb = discord.Embed(
        title='Удаление сообщения ',
        color=red,
        timestamp=message.created_at
    )
  emb.add_field(name="Пользователь:", value=f"{message.author.mention}", inline=False)
  emb.add_field(name='Канал:', value=f'<#{message.channel.id}>', inline=False)
  emb.add_field(name='Сообщение:', value=f'{message.content}', inline=False)
  emb.add_field(name='ID сообщения:', value=f'`{message.id}`', inline=False)
  emb.set_footer(text='Логи Сообщений | Arizona Space')
  await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```